# Want to convert Dynamic PL/SQL query into static one

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In my project there is one lengthy dynamic query which is as below-

```
basic_query varchar2(1000);
final_query varchar2(1500);
where_clause varchar2(500) default null;

basic_query :=<select ...from table where ....>

If(<condition1>)
    then 
    where_clause := <one_new_condition_will_be_added_in_where_clause1>
elsif(<condition2>)
    then 
    where_clause := <one_new_condition_will_be_added_in_where_clause2>
elsif(<condition3>)
    then 
    where_clause := <one_new_condition_will_be_added_in_where_clause3>
else  
    where_clause := <one_new_condition_will_be_added_in_where_clause4>
endif;



final_query :=basic_query || where_clause || '<group_by_clause'> || <'order_by_clause'>;

execute immediate final_query;
```

Now my client wants to convert this dynamic query to static one. I have tried it with using CASE,but it's not working properly.

```
select ...from table where condition1,and 
case(
when(<condition1> and <one_new_condition_will_be_added_in_where_clause1>)
    then 'valid'
when(<condition2> and <one_new_condition_will_be_added_in_where_clause2>
    then 'valid'
when(<condition1> and <one_new_condition_will_be_added_in_where_clause3>)
    then 'valid'
when(<condition2> and <one_new_condition_will_be_added_in_where_clause4>
        then 'valid'
    else 'invalid'
end;)='valid
```

It is checking the conditions given in CASE clause & if any one of is true,it gives output without adding these conditions in where clause.

Hope someone will understand  this problem & will give the solution.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: Your "new" query also appears to be dynamic - `<one_new_condition_will_be_added_in_where_clause1>`. At present this question is so vague that I have no idea what is being asked.

Comment: Also, "Now my client wants to convert this dynamic query to static one" - why is your client telling you **how** to write your code?

Comment: In principle what you're doing with `case` will work, so I think some detail has been lost in your simplification for posting. I suspect the equivalent of the final `else` in the original is too lax, as it would have to negate all the previous conditions (but it's unclear if you're doing that since you've repeated conditions 1 and 2, which doesn't look right at all). Also can't tell if dynamic SQL is appropriate here - depends what the actual conditions are. If it is then I'd also query why your client disagrees. The reason to switch *might* inform an alternative approach.

Comment: This problem is called "Dynamic where clause". Go to asktom a there you will find several articles about it.

Comment: Tell your client that as long as the code produces valid results and executes in a reasonable amount of time it's none of their business how it's done.  (We once had a client demand to see the source code for a product to make sure it was "really written in C++".  When we asked why (preparatory to blowing them off) the response was "All software in our organization must be written in C++".  When asked what language MS-DOS (it was that long ago :-) was written in they gave us a look of abject horror.  I don't know if Microsoft ever answered their question.  I know we never did :-).

Comment: Yup.I can perused my client. But i am keen to find the solution of problem :)

Comment: @Mark there can be various reasons. For example each dynamic query has it's own sql_id, it's own execution plan, it's own record in active session history, ... I saw situation when the text of such SQL queries occupied about 40GB of DB server's RAM while buffer cache size was reduced to 15MB. Dynamic query more-or-less implies hard parse. Sometimes it's necessary sometimes it's evil.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use PL/SQL function in the code.

```
select ...from table where 'Y' = IsRecordValid(...all relevant values in conditions...);
```

And implement the evaluation there. I am not sure about your considaration about performance, but you maybe interested in function based index to improve your performance.

Other approach is to use **dbms_sql** package which you can use to create dynamically SQL but keep almost all benefits of static query.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Is there any solution by using CASE?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, in principle using `case` as you have shown should work (where by 'work' I mean produce the same result; which doesn't necessarily mean it's any better and could have performance and maintenance implications etc.). To demonstrate I'll create some dummy data:

```
create table t42 (flag varchar2(1), value varchar2(10), cond number);
insert into t42 values ('Y', 'One', 1);
insert into t42 values ('Y', 'Two', 2);
insert into t42 values ('Y', 'Three', 3);
```

... and two procedures in a package:

```
create package p42 as
procedure proc1(parm number);
procedure proc2(parm number);
end p42;
/

create package body p42 as

procedure proc1(parm number) is
    basic_query varchar2(1000);
    final_query varchar2(1500);
    where_clause varchar2(500) default null;
    result t42.value%type;
begin
    basic_query := 'select value from t42 where flag = ''Y'' ';

    if parm = 2013 then
        where_clause := 'and cond = 1 ';
    elsif parm = 2012 then
        where_clause := 'and cond = 2 ';
    else
        where_clause := 'and cond = 3 ';
    end if;

    final_query := basic_query || where_clause;
    execute immediate final_query into result;
    dbms_output.put_line(result);
end proc1;

procedure proc2(parm number) is
    result t42.value%type;
begin
    select value into result from t42 where flag = 'Y'
    and case
        when parm = 2013 and cond = 1 then 'valid'
        when parm = 2012 and cond = 2 then 'valid'
        when not (parm = 2013 or parm = 2012) and cond = 3 then 'valid'
        else 'invalid' end = 'valid';
    dbms_output.put_line(result);
end proc2;

end p42;
/
```

So `proc1` is essentially doing what your original dynamic query does, I believe. `proc2` is using your `case` construct. Clearly the conditions are completely made up and the variable `where` clause would be stupid in this form, but this is only about the `case`.

Running with various values for parm (2013, 2012, 2011) gives the same row back through both procedures, so they're equivalent in that sense

```
exec p42.proc1(2013);

One

exec p42.proc2(2013);

One
```

I suspect you've got the final condition wrong. Of course I'm guessing, since the pseudocode you've posted is so far removed form your actual query that we can't see what you might have done wrong. But if you did something like this:

```
    and case
        when parm = 2013 and cond = 1 then 'valid'
        when parm = 2012 and cond = 2 then 'valid'
        when cond = 3 then 'valid'
        else 'invalid' end = 'valid';
```

... then `cond = 3` would be evaluated for all the rows that hadn't already matched on an earlier case, regardless of the value of `parm` - e.g. if `parm = 2013` and `cond = 3`, which your original dynamic version would not have picked up. With `2013` you'd match `One` and `Three`. So you'd need to exclude all the `parm` values that you'd used as conditions earlier, and only then look at `cond = 3`:

```
    and case
        when parm = 2013 and cond = 1 then 'valid'
        when parm = 2012 and cond = 2 then 'valid'
        when not (parm = 2013 or parm = 2012) and cond = 3 then 'valid'
        else 'invalid' end = 'valid';
```

So in your pseudocode, that might mean:

```
select ... from table where condition1 and  case
    when (<condition1> and <one_new_condition_will_be_added_in_where_clause1>)
        then 'valid'
    when (<condition2> and <one_new_condition_will_be_added_in_where_clause2>
        then 'valid'
    when (<condition3> and <one_new_condition_will_be_added_in_where_clause3>)
        then 'valid'
    when (not (<condition1> or <condition2> or <condition3>)
        and <one_new_condition_will_be_added_in_where_clause4>)
        then 'valid'
    else 'invalid'
end = 'valid'
```

I'm not necessarily saying this is a good idea, just that it ought to work. Without knowing why your client objects to dynamic SQL (all of it? some specific aspect of your query? some impact you're having on the database, e.g. through not using bind variables?) and what your real query is doing it's impossible to know if this approach is appropriate. There may be a much better way, and that might be improving the dynamic version for all we know...